# driver.quit() and driver.close() methods are not working inside @AfterTest method

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber, bdd

I'm using Selenium using both Java and Cucumber. And I'm curious when I'm using `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()` under `@AfterTest` method, browser won't closed and when I'm using it inside my test step i.e `@Test` annotated method. It's called perfectly within steps.

Refer below code for the same :

```
@Then("^I see Dashboard$")
public void iSeeDashboard() throws Throwable {
    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
    Assert.assertEquals(lp.TitleId().getText(),"Mengelola User Customer");
    log.info("Successfully Login");
    driver.quit();
}
```

And here the whole code and I want to put `driver.quit` under `@AfterTest`

```
public class LoginStep extends steps.BaseStep {
public static Logger log = 
LogManager.getLogger(steps.BaseStep.class.getName());


@BeforeTest
public void before() throws IOException
{
   driver = initializeDriver();
   log.info("Driver is Initialized");
}

@Given("^I navigate to Website$")
public void iNavigateToWebsite() throws IOException {
    driver = initializeDriver();
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("URL"));
    log.info("Navigate to Website");
}

@Then("^I enter username and password")
public void iEnterUsernameAndPassword() throws IOException {
    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
    lp.UsernameId().sendKeys("xxx");
    lp.PasswordId().sendKeys("xxx");
    log.info("Successfully entered valid credentials");
}

@When("^I click Login$")
public void iClickLogin() throws Throwable {
    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
    lp.LoginId().click();
}

@Then("^I see Dashboard$")
public void iSeeDashboard() throws Throwable {
    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
    Assert.assertEquals(lp.TitleId().getText(),"Lorem ipsum");
    log.info("Successfully Login");
    //driver.quit();
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

Any explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

`@BeforeTest, @AfterTest` annotations are not supported since Cucumber doesn't has the concept of test. It has features and you are executing the steps in Given, When & And, Then format. So in your case Cucumber only understands your steps not Tests.

Use `@BeforeFeature` & `@AfterFeature` which was Cucumber understands the hooks.

See the [list of cucumber supported hook here.](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/wdio.conf.js#L311-L322)

Also not framework related hooks work with Cucumber like-
onPrepare, beforeSession, afterSession and onComplete.

Comment: +1 Perfect, I was trying the same things in few months back and caught the same issue but its get resolved after using latest Cucumber Hooks like AfterFeature & BeforeFeature.
So, go ahead with AfterFeature annotation man.

Comment: @bharatmane
I do not think `@BeforeFeature` and `@AfterFeature` work with cucumber framework. These work with specflow. Cucumber still to implement these annotations